# how to find sub character in notepade++ with asccii code 026

Tags: notepad++, subscript, ctrl

I tested <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, searched in Setting Shortcut Mapper... and Typed ALT+026 .

Also checked all shortcut possible on keyboard, but wasn't successful to find `"SUB"` character.

Please help me.
thanks!

Comment: My version of Notepad++ (6.9.1) worked just fine with the search box (CTRL+F) and typing ALT+026 and then click in Find button.

Comment: My NPP (Win, v7.2.2) *Find What* field behaves in a very strange way when I try to use the ALT+code combinations, and does not let entering the SUB char directly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess that the developers corrected some bug on it generating this behavior of yours as collateral side effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way after a while :))
it is an special command written "sub" with a black background I cached it by removing the short cut saved it the setting of notepad++ and then push ctrl+Z

Answer (score 4):

Turn on the **Regular expression** checkbox, and type into the **Find What** field:

```
\x1A
```

Here, `1A` is the hex value of the SUB char.

See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the hex codes of the chars you need to search for.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a special dialog `Find Characters in Range...`. You find it in the `Search` menu. It is a useful supplement to the usual search dialog.

Just enter `My Range` 26 - 26 , mark `Wrap Around` if necessary and hit `Find`.

Comment: Yes, it is at the end of the menu options. Also, it allows to use decimal codes instead of hex ones.

Comment: Didn't even knew this feature! Thanks. +1